# MediaLibrary Pro livewire file upload 401 error HttpException

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have error when trying upload media file via MediaLibraryPro on laravel. I get 401 error
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",

This doesn't happening on local only when i try uploading on server ( i use kubernetes and cert-manager ssl)
I also use s3 to upload images
does anyone has same error ? how i can fix it.

I already checked timeout ,middleware and csrf but all seems ok.

Comment: facing the same case, have you got it to fixed?